Open URL prefilling basic auth
On our lan we have a simple web page with buttons that open various internal sites.
Clicking the button opens the URL in a new tab. This is done using:
var win = window.open('http://' + url, '_blank');
win.focus();

When the new page opens the basic auth popup appears and we have to fill this in and click sign in.  Is there any way to populate this using javascript or jquery and click sign in ?
I've tried the following, but nothing happened when I clicked the button.
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', url, async, username, password)
xhr.send()

Thanks

You can include basic auth parameters in the URL: https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters. Obviously, you need to be wary of exposing user credentials.

I do not think you can do that anymore

I'm not looking to pass the username and password within the URL, I was hoping there was another way to do this.

Consider implementing SSO (Single Sign On) on your LAN.  If you are using windows logins / active directory then consider using Windows Authentication in your app instead of Forms Authentication (windows login becomes the SSO). (this assumes the login/pwd will be the same across apps, given that you want to pre-fill these, it seems a safe assumption)

There is no way to use JavaScript to access the basic HTTP authentication fields because, when they appear, the main thread is blocked just as if you had called window.prompt().
That being said, you can include basic authentication parameters in the URL when the navigation is initiated from JavaScript.  For example, I have a bookmarklet that will log me into my router:
javascript:void(window.location.href = 'http://admin:password@192.168.1.1/');

Do keep in mind this usage carries an increased security risk.
EDIT
While you can't access the auth popup from JavaScript, you can establish a browser session using XMLHttpRequest followed by navigation:
async function doBasicAuthentication(url, username, password) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, false, username, password);
  xhr.send('');
  if (xhr.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error(`Basic Authentication Request to "${url}" Failed with HTTP Status ${xhr.status}`);
  }
  location.href = url;
}


As already noted in the comments, this feature has or is about to be removed from browsers.

And, as already noted in the comments, OP is "not looking to pass the username and password within the URL"

This doesn't work, it still pops up the basic auth box requesting credentials.

Answer is there is no way to do it with JavaScript unless we're talking browser extension with messaging to a native instrumentation app for the browser.
When navigation is initiated by setting window.location programatically rather than a direct address bar load, the feature still works in most major browsers on Windows 11 (Except IE and Brave) and in Chrome, Edge, and Samsung Internet on Android 13.
@Tom ensure your username/password doesn't contain any of these for URL use: :/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=
Also, hold for edit on answer for another alternative.

@ChuckTerry thanks that does work :) Although I have hit an issue with a couple of our links as they are to other sites owned by us on different domains.. so I'm getting CORS errors.  I'll mark this as the answer as it does do what I asked. Thanks

Thanks!  I had actually forgotten that XHR could handle basic auth after CORS was implemented.  You could always set up a simple forwarding proxy on your intranet to modify CORS related headers for those sites on other domains if necessary :)
